# Tocloft customizations not working for algorithm's list

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, algorithm2e

I have been fighting with tocloft to get it to apply some customizations across all the listings, but it seems that they only work for the default ones like "tocs", "lofs" and "lots". For the ones defined by me or the ones like algorithms with its own "loa" it does not work:

```
\documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \usepackage{algorithm2e}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{red}{RGB}{180,40,50}

    \makeatletter
    \begingroup
      \let\newcounter\@gobble
      \let\setcounter\@gobbletwo
      \globaldefs\@ne
      \let\c@loadepth\@ne
      \newlistof{algorithmt}{loa}{\listalgorithmcfname}
    \endgroup
    \let\l@algorithm\l@algorithms
    \makeatother

    \renewcommand\cftdotsep{0}
    \renewcommand\cftdot{\color{red}\_}

    \renewcommand\cftalgorithmtdotsep{0}
    \renewcommand\cftalgorithmtleader{\color{red}\_}


    \begin{document}

        \tableofcontents
        \listofalgorithms
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}
        \listoftables
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

        \chapter{chapter one}
            \section{section one}
                \begin{table}
                \centering A
                \caption{test table}
                \end{table}

                \begin{algorithm}
                \centering A
                \caption{test algorithm}
                \end{algorithm}

        \chapter{chapter two}
            \section{section one}
                \begin{table}
                \centering A
                \caption{another test table}
                \end{table}

                \begin{algorithm}
                \centering A
                \caption{another test algorithm}
                \end{algorithm}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `.loa` file you'll see

```
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\contentsline {algocf}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces test algorithm}}{5}
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\contentsline {algocf}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces another test algorithm}}{7}
```

so, rather than `\let\l@algorithm\l@algorithms` you have to say

```
\let\l@algocf\l@algorithmt
```

Some other adjustments must be made. Here's the complete example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{180,40,50}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \let\newcounter\@gobble
  \let\setcounter\@gobbletwo
  \globaldefs\@ne
  \let\c@loadepth\@ne
  \newlistof{algorithmt}{loa}{\listalgorithmcfname}
\endgroup
\let\l@algocf\l@algorithmt
\makeatother

\renewcommand\cftdotsep{0}
\renewcommand\cftdot{\color{red}\_}

\renewcommand\cftalgorithmtdotsep{0}
\let\cftalgorithmtleader\cftsecleader


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listofalgorithms
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\chapter{chapter one}
\section{section one}
\begin{table}
\centering A
\caption{test table}
\end{table}

\begin{algorithm}
\centering A
\caption{test algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\chapter{chapter two}
\section{section one}
\begin{table}
\centering A
\caption{another test table}
\end{table}

\begin{algorithm}
\centering A
\caption{another test algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You probably want to set also the indentation to a proper value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For the indentation I just added

\let\cftalgorithmtindent\cftsecindent

and everything looks like I wanted.